# Is is possible in Datadog to query within a query

Tags: datadog

I am new to Datadog, and I need to do a search that may not be possible. I can write this most succinctly in SQL.

```
SELECT * FROM LOGS WHERE RequestID IN 
     (SELECT RequestID FROM LOGS WHERE FooID = @SomeID)
```

In my scenario, RequestID follows a single API call through the life of that call. However, the API accepts multiple calls on the same Foo in a series. I would like to be able to see everything related to the series of calls. The above query would achieve that for me.